# Can VPN,proxy servers and TOR evade/remove Browser Fingerprinting in terms of anonymity?

Tags: vpn, proxy, tor, anonymity, forensics

If not what are other ways to beat browser fingerprinting?Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By themselves no. Browser fingerprinting involves measuring things like screen size, extensions, allowed scripts, and fonts (both browser and computer) as well as many other factors. These are often unique to your browser (hence the name) so VPN, Proxy Servers and Tor connections will not remove this information. They protect the channel of communication, not the communication itself.

However the Tor Browser (in its default state) can defeat browser fingerprinting. By keeping all of the measurable uniqueness the same across all installations you can not tell which browser is which. That is why (at least in Tails) it warns you when you maximize your browser. You have made your browser slightly more unique then the general Tails Tor browser.

This assumes passive fingerprinting. If you allow active fingerprint which includes: execution of code, storage of cookies and reporting of computer unique meta-data (i. e. mac address) as well as other data. Then it is trivial to extract an unique id for a computer and browser. If active fingerprinting is not blocked it is almost impossible to avoid fingerprinting.

Comment: Thanks,your answer really says it all.I have a doubt,how do we disable active fingerprinting?

Comment: I understand how to stop storage of cookies and execution of code (related to javascript execution).But reporting of MAC address,please if you could explain..

Comment: The only times that I have seen the Mac Address pulled involved using ActiveX scripting through IE (or ActiveX through Javascript, Java ect. for other browsers). To the best of my knowledge it is not revealed in any modern browser by default. However it is pretty much the definition of a fingerprint and can be retrieved so I included it in my answer.